# What is user's quote?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, user-expectation, ux-field, users

Im new to the field of User Experience and currently studying on how to conduct user research and gather helpful data from various users to figure out or have an idea who's Im designing for. But along the way, I've come across this word "user quote". I tried to google this word but I can't come up with a relevant result. The same thing I've done here.

Can anyone kindly give me an idea about this and how to get such thing from the user? I mean, what kind of questions do I need to ask for me to get a "user quote".

Any help, suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you're seeing this in the context of a report or presentation, it might literally mean quotes from user interviews or usability studies—things your participants said that seems particularly poignant, summary, or relatable. Including participants' actual words can help keep the research presentation grounded in reality and humanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact use of this differs among professionals even, so you're not going to get a definitive answer.

That said, I use it to give a sort of **most important idea brought up by the user**, which is especially useful when communicating your results to non-UX people (usually a manager of some sort).

As an example, let's say you were doing UX research on a frying pan, and Mary's feedback (direct or indirect) was said that she found the pan handle comfortable, and she liked the surface overall, but the weight of the pan made it hard for her to use.  Her user quote may be "too heavy".  You have to make a decision as to what of her feedback is most important and essentially summarise it as that.

Comment: Hello John, thanks also for sharing your copious stand on this. Both of you guys really helps me gain more added value insights towards learning UX. Just enough rich data and probably I'll take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the field of UX. There is no standart definition for the term "user quote". User quote will probably mean some **user feedback**. Or what one user has said about your application or website. It can be translated as **user opinion**.

In usability and UX field we gather user opinions and take them very seriously into account. Then we use those opinions or "quotes" and make changes to the website or app according to them.

Its like when you are at a restaurant and they ask you did you liked the steak, and you say, aww maybe if you grill it a bit more it will be better. So next time the chef will make it according to your feedback or "quote". The same is with website and apps - we collect user feedback, quotes, opinions, we observe them and then make changes following their advices.

If you give me the source where you have spot this term I will get you more specific answer.

Comment: What if the steak was perfectly grilled but just served cold? You would be surprised the solutions people come up with while the real problem is completely unrelated.

Comment: Hello Kristiyan, thanks for sharing your thoughts regarding this. Really helps me to have an insight on some of the terms that perhaps used very often in the field of UX.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the user research field. As other contributors explained "user quote" is mostly referred to the verbatim or what users say. It is just one form of data, but it is especially effective in creating empathy in stakeholders that are not as familiar with the field of UX or ways to synthesize other forms of data such as observation.

If you heard people saying "user quote" there is a possibility that they are actually saying "user quota" in the context of recruiting participants or user groups with certain criteria.